# OpenCL vector data type usage

Tags: opencl

I'm using a GPU driver that is optimized to work with 16-element vector data type.
However, I'm not sure how to use it properly.

- Should I declare it as, for example, `cl_float16` on host with a size 16 times less than the original array?
- What is the better way to access this type on the OpenCL kernel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In host code you can use `cl_float16` host type. Access it like an array (e.g., `value.s[5]`). Pass as kernel argument. In kernel, access like `value.s5`.

Comment: You just pass it as a simple buffer?

Comment: No, not as a buffer (`clBuffer`) but just as a parameter, like an int.

Answer (score 0):

How you declare it on the host is pretty much irrelevant. What matters is how you allocate it, and even that only if plan on creating the buffer with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR and your GPU uses system memory. This is because your memory needs to be properly aligned for GPU zero-copy, otherwise the driver will create a background copy. If your GPU doesn't use system memory for buffers, or you don't use CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, then it doesn't matter - the driver will allocate a proper buffer on the GPU.

Your bigger issue is that your GPU needs to **work with** 16-element vectors. You will have to vectorize every kernel you want to run on it. IOW every part of our algorithms need to work with `float16` types. If you just use simple floats, or you declare the buffer as `global float16* X` but then use element access (X.s0, X.w and such) and work with those, the performance will be the same as if you declared the buffer `global float* X` - very likely crap.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
So, what your saying is that I must use _CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR_ flag to work with host memory, right? 
Regarding to the access to the buffer on the kernel: if I should not access by element (X.s0), how should I do it? Maybe X[index]?